# Disable save password prompt in chromium kiosk mode

Tags: google-chrome

We're developing an application for the raspberry pi which runs headless and opens up a chrome browser when launch is done. So if the user now enters credentials, chrome prompts with "Do you want Chromium to save your password for this site?"

So how can we disable this popup? I already searched the params for that but didn't found anything about that.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this same problem, and I solved it by setting up a [policy](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#PasswordManagerEnabled) file:

**`/etc/chromium/policies/managed/no-password-management.json`**

```
{
    "AutoFillEnabled": false,
    "PasswordManagerEnabled": false
}
```

I was not able to find a way to do this with command-line flags, however.

Comment: Since M70 the [`AutoFillEnabled` policy is deprecated](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#AutoFillEnabled) and superseded by `AutoFillAddressEnabled` and `AutoFillCreditCardEnabled`

Comment: @Septatrix please note its Autofill (with a lowercase f). Thanks for the tip, got me almost there!